# Disabling Eclipse errors dialogue

Tags: eclipse, popup

When I make changes in eclipse and press the save button a dialog box pops up that says 'Problems occurred'. For developing reasons these occurred errors don't matter to me, so my question is there a possibility to disable this popup its really annoying?
The popup looks like this:
[image]

Comment: what type of eclipse did you used?

Comment: Click the details button and post the screenshot again. In the details is the source of the problem, which might help to understand which plugin is causing the problem. And that might lead to a real answer of what to do, anything else is just bad random guessing.